# How can I query for the chronological order of entities?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-room

I want to store the chronological order of the entities in my database.

My table looks kind of like this:

```
_id     name     start_time    
  0     Ababab   01.04.2020    
  1     Bababa   02.03.2020    
  2     Cababa   09.04.2020
```

I want to sort the entities by the start_time, and remember the entity which chronologically happened before. Like this:

```
_id     name     start_time    chronologically_previous
  1     Bababa   02.03.2020    -
  0     Ababab   01.04.2020    1
  2     Cababa   09.04.2020    0
```

It should be possible to add an arbitrary new entity, and chronologically_previous should be updated accordingly.

Until now, I have tried monstrous SQL queries....

```
@Query("UPDATE episode SET previous_cycle_id = 
    (SELECT LEAD(_id) OVER (ORDER BY start_date ASC) FROM episode)")
```

Didn't work.

And shouldn't it be a simpler solution out there? Maybe saving the order in an array, in another object, in another database, I don't know..

I am quite new to Kotlin and room and everything, so I appreciate ideas of an elegant solution!

Edit:

Actually, I am most interested in the **time difference** between an entity and the previous. I am also interested in the average time difference.

These time gap values are needed all over my app. Therefore, I would like to store them somehow, so that I avoid a lot of database operations the whole time.

**Solution:** When I add a new entity, I leave the time_gap field empty (null). Then, in a next run, I query for the sorted list of the entities. In this list, I find the index of the recently added item. I update the time_gap field with the value of the "previous neighbour" (index - 1) in the list. If the recent element is not the last one in the list, I also update the time_gap field of the "next neighbour" (index + 1).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`lag()`](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html):

```
select e.*, 
       lag(_id) over (order by start_time) as prev_id
from episode e;
```

I would not recommend storing this in the table.  It is rather complicated to keep it up-to-date for data modifications.